# Realtime data transport architecture

Tags: java, websocket, real-time, scalability

I have a concept of a game system that includes (preferably) Java server and multi-platform clients (Web, Android, iOS).

This is a 1vs1 player-vs-player realtime game. Servers performs a matchup of 2 players. So basically server needs to handle many matches containing 2 players. Both players alter same data, and each player should be updated in realtime with actions of other player.

Can you suggest me:

1) Server-side framework/library that would ease the implementation, as I would rather not start learning node.js from the scratch. :) Vert.x comes to mind.

2) Should clients hold the replica of the data, and alter it locally (meaning only data that is transfered are only commands, here I see JMS as good solution), or should only server alter the data and then send the complete data set every time change occurs?

3) How should the data be transfered? Considering the multi-platform requirement only thing I see viable are WebSockets.

4) An example/tutorial of server handling pairing of WebSocket connections? All I ever found are 1-to-1 connections.

5) Considering scalability, can you explain how could all this work in a distributed environment?

Comment: On multiplayer game architecture and real-time web frameworks, you can refer to this article and this talk of mine:

- "Optimizing Multiplayer 3D Game Synchronization Over the Web"
(http://blog.lightstreamer.com/2013/10/optimizing-multiplayer-3d-game.html)

- "More Than Just WebSockets for Real-Time Multiplayer Games and Collaboration"
(http://blog.lightstreamer.com/2013/12/html5devconf-more-than-just-websockets.html)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I don't think node.js is such big deal to learn. I would personally prefer a well known - broadly used framework.

2) If you are considering mobile, probably the first option seems more sound. You should consider send/push deltas during the game, and still provide functionality to retrieve the full state of the game in case the client disconnect and connect with same ID.

3) WebSocket would be the best option. Push approach, TLS option and [well supported](http://caniuse.com/websockets). Another option is the WebRTC data connection, that is peer-2-peer most of the times. I say most of the times because if one of the users is behind a dynamic NAT router or restrictive firewall, it won't be possible, and you will need a TURN (relay) server. Anyway, [it is less supported](http://caniuse.com/rtcpeerconnection) than WS.

4) You should not "pair websockets". The WS connections just input commands to your logic, and your logic broadcast events to whoever it wants. Despite of being a 1vs1 game, probably you want to inspect the flow of events for further debugging or analysis. So consider WS as a transport, not as an entity.

5) Very, very, very broad question. But assuming that you are going to use WS, and that your application will be so successful that you will need multiple servers... assume that it is impossible to predict that two users will connect to the same server, so you should consider a message bus that allow to play users from one server with the users in other server. An EDA (Event Driven Architecture) would make sense.